# How to upgrade WPF file without custom action as mouse click

Tags: c#, wpf

I made setup file in visual studio by setup installer.

I finished program installing. And now I want to install file by another program as update launcher. but, I don't know, how to do.

A program Version 1.0.0

Update launcher -> Setup file executing -> A program Update ->
A Program Version 1.0.1.
how to execute programmatically setup.msi file in Update launcher program.

Comment: please give more details. I've read your question twice and still don't know what you are tryin to do

Comment: sorry, I simply want to upgrade by setup installer, but I want not to click by customer. example, next button of setup installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to install msi use the following code:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/i <path to installer>.msi";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

When you click on msi on windows it runs msiexec command.

To see possible parameters (i.e for silent install without user interaction) go [here](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/msiexec.html).

Comment: but, I want not click button.

Comment: @김태형 check the link in the answer. there is a parameter for `quiet mode (there is no user interaction)`

Comment: Hello. I have a more question. I want to upgrade using msi file.But, your code is not updated. How to upgrade?? I don't know how to create msp file. Also, when I change version value of setup installer, and than product code is changed.....

Comment: @김태형 You should not change product code, but version. In this case everything will be fine. You don't need msp. msp is a patch, but you want to update app. I think your question is related to the tool by which you create msi, not the way you launch it.